# MySQL Query Optimization eliminate unnecessary joins

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

Conceptually, I am trying to grab 8 separate survey scores for every user in my system. I want to output all 8 scores connected to a given user outputted on the same  row. Here is my best shot to achieve this:

```
SELECT cp.CONSUMER_ID,
       bsr1.SCORE AS SET_1_SCORE,
       bsr2.SCORE AS SET_2_SCORE,
       bsr3.SCORE AS SET_3_SCORE,
       bsr4.SCORE AS SET_4_SCORE,
       bsr5.SCORE AS SET_5_SCORE,
       bsr6.SCORE AS SET_6_SCORE,
       bsr7.SCORE AS SET_7_SCORE,
       bsr8.SCORE AS SET_8_SCORE
FROM 
CONSUMER_PROFILE AS cp
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr1
ON bsr1.SET_ORDER=1 
AND bsr1.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr2
ON bsr2.SET_ORDER=2
AND bsr2.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr3
ON bsr3.SET_ORDER=3
AND bsr3.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr4
ON bsr4.SET_ORDER=4
AND bsr4.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr5
ON bsr5.SET_ORDER=5
AND bsr5.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr6
ON bsr6.SET_ORDER=6
AND bsr6.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr7
ON bsr7.SET_ORDER=7
AND bsr7.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr8
ON bsr8.SET_ORDER=8
AND bsr8.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
```

This returns the proper output, but however is terribly slow. How would you suggest I optimize it?

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need is an index on survey_scores(SET_ORDER, consumer_id, score) or at least survey_scores(SET_ORDER, consumer_id).  It will then work quite well even with your query.

An alternative way to write it would be

```
SELECT cp.CONSUMER_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsr1.SET_ORDER=1 THEN bsr1.SCORE END) AS SET_1_SCORE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsr1.SET_ORDER=2 THEN bsr1.SCORE END) AS SET_2_SCORE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsr1.SET_ORDER=3 THEN bsr1.SCORE END) AS SET_3_SCORE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsr1.SET_ORDER=4 THEN bsr1.SCORE END) AS SET_4_SCORE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsr1.SET_ORDER=5 THEN bsr1.SCORE END) AS SET_5_SCORE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsr1.SET_ORDER=6 THEN bsr1.SCORE END) AS SET_6_SCORE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsr1.SET_ORDER=7 THEN bsr1.SCORE END) AS SET_7_SCORE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsr1.SET_ORDER=8 THEN bsr1.SCORE END) AS SET_8_SCORE
FROM CONSUMER_PROFILE AS cp
LEFT JOIN survey_scores AS bsr1
ON bsr1.SET_ORDER in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
AND bsr1.CUSTOMER_ID=cp.CONSUMER_ID
GROUP BY cp.CONSUMER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly tune this further:

```
SELECT ... FROM consumer_profile as cp    
LEFT JOIN survey_scores as bsr1  
ON ((bsr1.Set_Order BETWEEN 1 AND 8)  
  AND (bsr1.Consumer_ID = cp.Consumer_ID))  
GROUP BY cp.Consumer_ID;
```

If you are sure the are *never* `Set_order` out of the range 1..8
then you can drop the `(bsr1.Set_Order BETWEEN 1 AND 8) AND` part.

Other then that Richard's answer is a thing of beauty.